# Testing Android NavigationView menu item with espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I've set up my NavigationDrawer and NavigationView using the newer menu/my-nav-menu.xml, instead of a ListView with Adapter. As part of my automation test using Espresso, I would like to assert a given menu item is visible, and then perform a click on that item. For my visibility check, I've tried the following...

```
onView(viewMatcher...).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Using this, I end up with a NoMatchingViewException.

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
hierarchy found matching: with id:
com.example.android:id/menuitem_my_item
```

From what I've gathered, it's possible that menu items are not visible on the view hierarchy. Has anyone with more experience testing on Android figured out a way around this?

Comment: could you add a screenshot how it looks? it would be easier to me explain you how to do it

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722349/android-espresso-click-on-navigation-drawer-item-with-image-and-text

Comment: I handed up find an issue related to my problem https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187701

Comment: so now it's solved, right? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This will navigate to register page even if menu item is not currently visible and it is somewhere else

```
onView(withId(R.id.nav_view)).perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id. nav_register));
```